# How can I access the row in a RowCommand event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to find a DropDown element in the GridView_RowCommand but it says that GridViewCommandEventArgs does not contain a definituon for 'Row'. I need to do this in this event because i am evaluating a GridView Command. See failing code below

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.CommandName == "Add")
  {
    DropDownList Myddl = null;
    ClientClass client = new ClientClass();

    Myddl = e.Row.FindControl("ddlClients") as DropDownList;
    if (Myddl != null)
       {
         updated = client.InsertUpdateClient(ClientID, 
           int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString()), departmentID);
        }
    else
      { 
        Labels.Text = "There was an error updating this client";
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
```

This is assuming what's firing off the RowCommand is a LinkButton.  Change that according.

Comment: I am sorry, I am kind of new to this.. where is it finding the drop down here? My drop down is in an ItemTemplate

Comment: oh i see something like this  GridView row = (GridView)(((DropDownList)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
            Myddl = row.FindControl("ddlClients") as DropDownList;

Comment: @ edcod81 - No! it wont cast! you must have to use either LinkButton or Button or ImageButton. Which button type you have used?

Comment: I changed it to button but get error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView'.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the @Stephen,

```
if (e.CommandName == "Add")
  {
    DropDownList Myddl = null;
    ClientClass client = new ClientClass();

   //Use this if button type is linkbutton
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);

   //Use this if button type is Button
   //GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);

    Myddl = row.FindControl("ddlClients") as DropDownList;
    if (Myddl != null)
       {
         updated = client.InsertUpdateClient(ClientID, 
           int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString()), departmentID);
        }
    else
      { 
        Labels.Text = "There was an error updating this client";
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much... I wish i could give you both answers... I tried to vote up but dont have enough priviledges

Comment: @edcod81 Buddy! Its not about vote. I'm glad you got it working.